# PyNetlogo s and p not defined

Tags: java, python, exception, undefined, netlogo

I have recently downloaded PyNetlogo and I am trying to run the provided Example 1 on the PyNetlogo website (https://pynetlogo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_docs/introduction.html). I keep getting an error of either 's is not defined' or 'p is not defined' depending on if I am looking at a turtle or patch variable respectively.

Here are my system details:
jdk 15.0.2,
python 3.6,
netlogo 6.0,
MacOS catalina 10.15.7

Should p and s be defined by the pynetlogo? Please let me know if there is a problem with my code or incompatibilities in my system. Thanks.

Below is the code and error:

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('white')
sns.set_context('talk')

import pyNetLogo

netlogo = pyNetLogo.core.NetLogoLink(gui=False, netlogo_home="/Applications/NetLogo 6.0/", 
                                     jvm_home = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib")

netlogo.load_model('/Applications/NetLogo 6.0/models/Sample Models/Biology/Wolf Sheep Predation.nlogo')
netlogo.command('setup')

countdown_df = netlogo.patch_report('countdown')

Nothing named P has been defined. at position 54 in 
    at org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception(Fail.scala:27)
    at org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception(Fail.scala:25)
    at org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception(Fail.scala:23)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$parseExpressionInternal$4(ExpressionParser.scala:392)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpressionInternal(ExpressionParser.scala:392)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.scala:303)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.reporterApp$1(ExpressionParser.scala:570)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.buildReporterLambda$1(ExpressionParser.scala:591)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseDelayedBlock(ExpressionParser.scala:620)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.resolveType(ExpressionParser.scala:274)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.resolveTypes(ExpressionParser.scala:128)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parsePotentiallyVariadicArgumentList(ExpressionParser.scala:91)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpressionInternal(ExpressionParser.scala:423)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.scala:303)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$parseExpressionInternal$1(ExpressionParser.scala:359)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseParenthesized(ExpressionParser.scala:318)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpressionInternal(ExpressionParser.scala:364)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseArgExpression(ExpressionParser.scala:231)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$parseArguments$1(ExpressionParser.scala:167)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$parseArguments$1$adapted(ExpressionParser.scala:166)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:156)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseArguments(ExpressionParser.scala:166)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parsePotentiallyVariadicArgumentList(ExpressionParser.scala:89)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseStatement(ExpressionParser.scala:70)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$apply$1(ExpressionParser.scala:31)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseStatements(ExpressionParser.scala:43)
    at org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.apply(ExpressionParser.scala:31)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.parseProcedure(NetLogoParser.scala:45)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.parseProcedure$(NetLogoParser.scala:29)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.parseProcedure(FrontEnd.scala:10)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.$anonfun$basicParse$1(NetLogoParser.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1406)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:210)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse(NetLogoParser.scala:25)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse$(NetLogoParser.scala:15)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.basicParse(FrontEnd.scala:10)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:27)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd$(FrontEnd.scala:25)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:10)
    at org.nlogo.compile.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:38)
    at org.nlogo.compile.Compiler.compileMoreCode(Compiler.scala:61)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.invokeCompiler(Evaluator.scala:162)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.evaluateReporter(Evaluator.scala:30)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluating.report(Evaluating.scala:102)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluating.report$(Evaluating.scala:101)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceScala.report(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:27)
    at NetLogoLinkV6.NetLogoLink.report(NetLogoLink.java:197)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in NetLogoLinkV6.NetLogoLink.report()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceScala.report()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluating.report$()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluating.report()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.evaluateReporter()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.invokeCompiler()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.compile.Compiler.compileMoreCode()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.compile.CompilerMain$.compile()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.frontEnd()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd$()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.basicParse()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse$()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.TraversableLike.map()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.Iterator.foreach()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.$anonfun$basicParse$1()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.parseProcedure()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.parseProcedure$()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.parseProcedure()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.apply()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseStatements()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$apply$1()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseStatement()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parsePotentiallyVariadicArgumentList()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseArguments()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$parseArguments$1$adapted()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$parseArguments$1()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseArgExpression()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpressionInternal()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseParenthesized()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$parseExpressionInternal$1()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpression()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpressionInternal()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parsePotentiallyVariadicArgumentList()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.resolveTypes()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.resolveType()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseDelayedBlock()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.buildReporterLambda$1()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.reporterApp$1()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpression()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.parseExpressionInternal()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in scala.Option.getOrElse()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.parse.ExpressionParser$.$anonfun$parseExpressionInternal$4()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-36m-darwin.so in org.nlogo.core.Fail$.exception()

Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

org.nlogo.core.CompilerException          Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyNetLogo/core.py in patch_report(self, attribute)
    432                 resultsvec = self.link.report('map [p -> [{0}] of p] \
--> 433                                                sort patches'.format(attribute))    
    434             resultsvec = self._cast_results(resultsvec)

org.nlogo.core.CompilerException: Nothing named P has been defined. at position 54 in 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NetLogoException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-afb3c5b5f1ad> in <module>
----> 1 countdown_df = netlogo.patch_report('countdown')

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/netlogo5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyNetLogo/core.py in patch_report(self, attribute)
    439         except jpype.JException as ex:
    440             print(ex.stacktrace())
--> 441             raise NetLogoException(str(ex))
    442 
    443     def patch_set(self, attribute, data):

NetLogoException: Nothing named P has been defined. at position 54 in
```

Comment: Please post code and errors as plain text.  Images just make it harder for us to help.

Comment: Hi John, sorry about that. The code is posted now.